# C# Regex Replace appends a newline character

Tags: c#, regex, newline

I'm reading the content of a config file and then trying to parse out a specific setting:

```
var content = File.ReadAllText(PsdFile);
var version = Regex.Replace(content, @"ModuleVersion\s+=\s+'(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)'", "$1.$2.$3");
```

I have the input file set to:

```
ModuleVersion = '3.1.11'\r\n
```

This is the VS variable preview.  The file contains a blank line at the end.
After executing the code above, the version variable contains:

```
3.1.11\r\n
```

So it's matched and identified the capture groups correctly but some reason it is appending \r\n.  I don't understand why.

It does seem to be related to the newline in the file.  If I remove the newline then the newline is not appended to the replaced string.  How can the final capture group match the final version triplet and the newline but exclude the single quote?

Comment: It does not append anything, it does not remove it in the first place. If you need to remove it, add `\r\n` or `[\r\n]*` at the end of the regex pattern. See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=ModuleVersion%5cs%2b%3d%5cs%2b%27%28%5cd%2b%29%5c.%28%5cd%2b%29%5c.%28%5cd%2b%29%27%5b%5cr%5cn%5d*&i=ModuleVersion+%3d+%273.1.11%27%0d%0a&r=%241.%242.%243).

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use standard serialization "techniques" like xml or json?

Comment: Not sure I understand. The file has a blank line before you run the code, and it still has one afterwards. And the purpose of the code was to capture some other values from the file. So...why would you expect it to have changed anything related to the newline? The newline is never removed, and it's never appended either. It's just always there. Perhaps you misunderstood what Regex.Replace is doing

Comment: It looks as if you just wanted [`var version = Regex.Match(content, @"(?<=ModuleVersion\s+=\s+')\d+(?:\.\d+)+").Value;`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dModuleVersion%5cs%2b%3d%5cs%2b%27%29%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%2b%29%2b&i=ModuleVersion+%3d+%273.1.11%27%0d%0a)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew answer it and you get the green tick. ;)

Comment: @aloisdg thanks, but that's the wrong PSD file.  I'm working on Powershell module descriptors, not Photoshop images.

Comment: @ADyson am I misunderstanding it?  Probably.  ;)  I think I get what you're saying though.  Wiktor's Match solution does what I need, but out of curiousity I modified my Replace statement to add ".*" to the start and end of the pattern.  I expected that to match any file contents preceding and proceeding the pattern, hence my replacement string would replace the the entire contents.  It got the \r but left the \n.  Any idea why?

Comment: @RichardPayne In a .NET regex, `.` matches any char but LF by default. If you want `.` to match any char, use `RegexOptions.Singleline` modifier option. Or, add a `(?s)` at the pattern start. Or, wrap the part of the pattern you need to match across lines with a modifier group - `(?s:.*)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  LOL, I did not know that.  Thanks Wiktor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Regex.Replace(content, @"ModuleVersion\s+=\s+'(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)'", "$1.$2.$3")` line of code performs a regex search of the `ModuleVersion\s+=\s+'(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)'` pattern, that is, it search for `ModuleVersion`, 1+ whitespaces, `=`, 1+ whitespaces, `'`, then it captures 1+ digits into Group 1, then matches a dot, then captures 1+ digits into Group 2, again matches a dot and places another 1+ digits into Group 3 and matches a `'` char, and then the whole match is replaced with Group 1 value, `.`, Group 2 value, `.` and Group 3 value.

So, as you see, that does nothing with the line break, and it makes little sense to capture those 3 groups as you still use the dots as a separator.

What you seem to be doing is extracting a value. Use `Regex.Match` to extract a single piece of text:

```
var version = "";
var m = Regex.Match(content, @"(?<=ModuleVersion\s+=\s+')\d+(?:\.\d+)+");
if (m.Success) {
    version = m.Value; 
}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DModuleVersion%5Cs%2B%3D%5Cs%2B%27%29%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B%29%2B&i=ModuleVersion%20%3D%20%273.1.11%27%0D%0A). Here, `(?<=ModuleVersion\s+=\s+')` is a lookbehind that requires `ModuleVersion`, 1+ whitespaces, `=`, 1+ whitespaces and `'` to appear immediately to the left of the current location.

Note that you may also use a *capturing* approach and get the result from `match.Groups[1].Value`:

```
var version = "";
var m = Regex.Match(content, @"ModuleVersion\s+=\s+'(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)");
if (m.Success) {
    version = m.Groups[1].Value; 
}
```